# 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a table in MYSQL with python. please someone can throw some light on this.

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student_details (first_name VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY, last_name VARCHAR(30), company_name VARCHAR(30), address VARCHAR(30), city VARCHAR(30),county VARCHAR(30), state VARCHAR(4), zip INT(6), phone1 VARCHAR(15), phone2 VARCHAR(15),email VARCHAR(50), web VARCHAR(50))")

row = 'James,Butt,Benton John B Jr,6649 N Blue Gum St,New Orleans,Orleans,LA,70116,504-621-8927,504-845-1427,jbutt@gmail.com,http://www.bentonjohnbjr.com'

cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO Student_details VALUES({row})")
```

Comment: You have to provide the quotes for varchar values

Answer (score -2):

Your Insert query is missing quotations for string values. Here is the modified version

```
create_query = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student_details (
       first_name VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY, 
       last_name VARCHAR(30), 
       company_name VARCHAR(30), 
       address VARCHAR(30), 
       city VARCHAR(30),
       county VARCHAR(30), 
       state VARCHAR(4), 
       zip INT(6), 
       phone1 VARCHAR(15), 
       phone2 VARCHAR(15), 
       email VARCHAR(50), 
       web VARCHAR(50)
)
"""
row = ("""
 INSERT INTO Student_details(first_name, last_name, company_name, address, city, county, state, zip, phone1, phone2, email, web)
   VALUES(
   'James', 'Butt', 'Benton John B Jr', '6649 N Blue Gum St', 'New Orleans', 'Orleans', 'LA', '70116', '504-621-8927', '504-845-1427', 'jbutt@gmail.com', 'http://www.bentonjohnbjr.com')
""")

cur.execute(create_query)
cur.execute(row)
```

Comment: What if a name is O'Neil? No, string interpolation is not the answer!

Comment: @shadow - this question and the linked answer are totally unrelated. I agree with you that we need to handle properly if you have single quotes within the values but the issue here is the way the values for the insert statement are constructed. If you see the row variable declaration, the values for varchar fields are not within quotes, just like integer values.

Comment: You correctly identified the problem, but the answer you proposed is no good enough. Btw, someone else closed the question, not me.